# camel netty4 message 1024 truncated..how can i solve it?

Tags: apache-camel, netty

i made a camel netty4 server program.and client sent 1119 byte message but my decoder truncated by 1024/95

here is my code.

```
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
    public static class BytesDecoder extends MessageToMessageDecoder<ByteBuf> {

        @Override
        protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("BytesDecoder readableBytes:"+msg.readableBytes());
            if (msg.isReadable()) {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[msg.readableBytes()];
                int readerIndex = msg.readerIndex();
                msg.getBytes(readerIndex, bytes);
                out.add(bytes);
            }
        }

    }
```

result ===>

BytesDecoder readableBytes:1024

BytesDecoder readableBytes:95

I want to get a full message byte 1119 byte.

Comment: Check the netty documentation about those codecs, they very likely has a default limit of 1024, which you need to re-configure to a higher value etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I already replied to this question on the netty mailinglist.

There is not guarantee that you will received all the data in one read call. Thus you will need to account for this by extending `ByteToMessageDecoder` and only read the bytes once there are at least 1024 readable.

For more example and details please see the javadocs of `ByteToMessageDecoder`.

Comment: Thanks.and can you show your source tip. I cant read a mailinglist.
Pz i have no enough time

Comment: i create this code using ByteToMessageDecoder BTW how can i handle my dynamic data.i could not know readableBytes size.